# Adding php with parameters with addCss in Magento

Tags: magento

I use a php file as stylesheet. This works pretty fine when there are no parameters

```
<action method="addCss">
  <stylesheet>style.php</stylesheet>
</action>
```

But as soon as I add a parameter to the request, Magento doesn't know anymore, that this file is in my own theme but uses the path to the default theme. Of course, as there is no file called style.php?param=val and so the common fallback is used. **But how can I force Magento to use my theme, no matter if it finds the file there or not?**

```
<action method="addCss">
  <stylesheet>style.php?param=val</stylesheet>
</action>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method addItem is less restrictive. addJs and addCss checks if file exists.
Try this instead :

```
<action method="addItem">
   <type>link_rel</type>
   <name>style.php?param=val</name>
   <params>rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"</params>
</action>
```

:)

Comment: Works like a charm except one little thing. Obviously, I have to add the path to the whole theme myself - relative to the document root. But my store isn't in the document root, so /skin/frontend/default/THEME/... doesn't work but it should be storepath/skin/frontend/default/THEME/... On the other hand I don't want to hardcode the path to the shop inside the theme as it might (and will) change on the production system. Is it possible access the shop root inside the xml-files?

Comment: You can't use "skin" logic with "other" item type sorry :(. You can overload/rewrite class Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head if you really need it (it is the class that handle AddItem/Js/Css layout actions)

Comment: I added a base-tag now that automaticly uses the base url. I still need to test if it makes any problems (as far as I know up to now, Magento makes every reference absolute, so there shouldn't be any dead links). But extending Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head would probably be a way better solution. Will try it tomorrow, thanks